# Displaying only the cropperjs preview without the actual cropper

Tags: cropperjs

I am new to CropperJs. I am working on a Angular application and I would like to display the CropperJs preview without displaying the actual cropper.

Is this possible? I so how?

Here is my code:

Html:

```
  <div class="preview">
    <img
      #image
      [src]="urlSafe"
    />
  </div>
```

Component:

```
  public cropper: any;
  @ViewChild('image', { static: false })
  public image: ElementRef;

  this.cropper = new Cropper(this.image.nativeElement, { preview: '.preview' });
  this.cropper.setAspectRatio(this.selectedRatio.value);
```

Can anyone please help?

**edit**: I have put together a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xerqiw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpreview%2Fpreview.component.ts

Can someone please have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Initializing CropperJS with this option hides the crop area:

`autoCrop: false`

Might need to also disable cropper to prevent a user from drawing the crop area manually:

`cropper.disable()`